# Regarding 3-fold connected coverings of the $S^1 \vee \mathbb{R} P^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology

As in the question, I need to determine all of the 3-fold connected coverings of the wedge of the unit circle and the real projective plane.

Here's what I think: I know that the fundamental group of $S^1$ is isomorphic to the set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$, and that the fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2$. Then I gather that by van Kampen's theorem, $\pi_{1}(S^1 \vee \mathbb{R}P^2)= \mathbb{Z}* \mathbb{Z}/2$. So this means that the universal cover of this space can be represented by a Cayley diagram involving copies of the real line $\mathbb{R}$ and the sphere $S^2$, which, unfortunately here I cannot display in a good picture. Would this at least be considered one of the 3-fold connected coverings of this space, and if so, how can I compute others, if they exist? Am I missing something?

Comment: «Would this at least be considered one of the 3-fold connected coverings of this space?» What *this*?

Comment: "This" is in reference to the Cayley diagram that represents the universal cover of this space. Go to the last page of this link: http://www.math.ku.dk/~moller/f03/algtop/opg/S1.3.pdf

Comment: How is that Caykey diagram "considered" one of the coverings of your space?

Comment: The Cayley diagram can serve as a covering, but it's $\infty$-fold, not $3$-fold.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, Andreas. WOW was I wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The coverings of a (well-behaved, connected) space $X$ are in correspondence with the conjugacy classes of subgroups of the fundamental group $\pi_1(X)$, and the degree of a covering corresponds to the index of the subgroup.

What you need to do, then, is to find all subgroups if index $3$ in $G=\mathbb Z*\mathbb Z/2$. If $H\subseteq G$ is such a group, then $G$ acts on the set $G/H$ of its cosets, of which there are three, and this gives us a map $f:G\to S(G/H)$, where $S(G/H)$ is the group of permutations of the set $G/H$. If we know $f$, then $H$ can be reconstructed as the preimage of the stabilizer of $H$ in $S(G/H)$.

Since $S(G/H)$ is isomorphic to $S_3$, the symmetric group on three letters, we need to find all morphisms $f:G\to S_3$ whose image is transitive, and compute the preimage of the stabilizers of points.

Now $S_3$ has exactly two transitive subgroups: its cyclic subgroup of order $3$ generated by $(1,2,3)$, and $S_3$ itself. It is not difficult to determine all surjective maps from $G$ to these two subgroups.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mariano.

Comment: How would we actually draw them? I get the algebra part, though.